# Is there a way to keep Windows EFS encryption metadata in place when uploading a file to Linux?

Tags: powershell, openssh, encrypting-file-system

I am trying to copy an EFS Encrypted zip file from Windows to a Linux server (through OpenSSH scp). It was encrypted using the PowerShell `.Encrypt()` method. Unfortunately, for whatever reason, when I download the file from the Linux server to a Windows machine, it can't be opened because the Windows machine does not detect it's EFS encrypted, and just regards it as an unreadable zip file.

I have exported the EFS key from the first computer and installed it on the computer that opens the file. The file is successfully detected as an EFS encrypted file when I use a USB key to move the file around and can be opened properly.

The PowerShell script that I'm trying to create should be invisible to the user. Another question is: could creating and mounting a VHDX file still be part of a script that doesn't interrupt the normal workflow of the user?

Comment: It's probably because you have EXT partition on your linux drive. See if you have NTFS on any other drive or try to set up file server (vs sftp)

Comment: I think it's not possible to use NTFS on the Linux server, because of the limitations of my hosting plan. Please clarify what do you mean by setting up file server (vs sftp)? You mean setting up a new NTFS server? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, like samba or even ftp server. Also, try to send some text file to/from linux to make sure this is not something specific to that file.

Comment: I stopped working on this project for a while. I formatted my Windows machine. I am restarting to work on this project.

The problem that this presents is different now. I can upload the zip file through Open SSH's `SCP` correctly. However, when I download it again, the Window's EFS encryption is disabled, and I can read the unencrypted contents of the zip file. Any ideas? Thanks,